MC Connect: There is no "Salesforce integration" under Setup SFMC
I have a urgent inquiry.
I was trying to connect SF to SFMC. At the step where you select "Salesforce Integration" under the setup menu for the API user created; I couldn't find it. Under Apps in SFMC I only have (Intalled packages & Google Analytics Integration) but not "Salesforce Integration".
Does anyone knows why ?
